# How to include resource key in resource value string

Tags: c#, xaml, localization, windows-8.1

I have Windows 8 application that is used for multiple branding, in my resource file there is key "AppName" which contains brand name, what I need is to include this key in the value fields where application name is required. for e.g. I want this type of entries in resource file

```
 1>"AppName" = "xyz"
 2>"WelcomeMessage" = "Welcome to "AppName" app"
 3>"Someotherstring" = "Blah BLah Blah "Appname" blah"
```

Comment: Get the `AppName` from code and bind it to the ui.

Comment: But I want to specify that in "resource.resw" file instead of doing it code behind

Comment: Are you trying to display some string in the `resource.resw` in one of the `Views` that your UI holds?

Comment: @CliveDM Edited post with more clarification, please refer to it

Comment: I don't get you, what do you mean by `include`?

Answer (score 0):

In the resources add a string resource with name "ApplicationTitle.Text" and the value of your 'AppName'.

Then create a TextBlock in your XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="ApplicationTitle" Text="" />
```

At runtime the `Text` of the `TextBlock` will be the value of the string resource.

Comment: I am aware this binding thing, but I am not asking for it. I edited my post with more clarification, please refer to it.

Comment: My answer explains how to use strings from resources.resw in your xaml. This is not data binding. It is what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by this:

In `Resource.resx`:

```
"AppName" : "Some-brand-name"
"WelcomeMessage" : "Welcome to $AppName$ app"
"Someotherstring" : "Blah blah blah $AppName$ blah"
```

And in the code:

```
 var appName = Properties.Resources.AppName;
 var welcomeMessage = Properties.Resources.WelcomeMessage.Replace("$AppName$", appName);
 var someotherstring = Properties.Resources.Someotherstring.Replace("$AppName$", appName);
```

Comment: Exactly, something like that, but in resource file.

Comment: What do you mean by `in resource file`? The `Resource.resx` is a `xml` formed data.

Comment: Maybe make the resouce string for example "Hello, welcome to %s app". And then replace the %s with the AppName string in code?

Comment: @BdR Are you saying something like my new answer?

Comment: @BdR I don't want to do anything in code behind, otherwise I should have put {0} in resource string and than used String.Format to get desired result. I want to nest resource string inside resource string, so "AppName" is resource , is there any special character which instruct that this is not a String but a resource key, something like "@AppName", "$AppName"

Comment: @Clive-DM yeah exactly like that. And I doubt it can be done without any code behind.

Comment: @BdR I highly doubt that. A `Resources.resx` is simply a place to store resources, it's like a warehouse, with absolutely no other function provided.